# Исправление асинхронного кода

Tags: python, asyncio

Я знаю что selenium не поддерживает асинхронность и перехожу в arsenic (асинхронный аналог selenium). И если в selenium код работает отлично, то в arsenic код как и полагается кликает на accept, но дальше не работает. В чем проблема? Вот, собственно, и сам асинхронный код:

```
import asyncio
from arsenic import get_session, browsers, services

async def flashscore():
    service = services.Chromedriver(binary="./chromedriver.exe")
    browser = browsers.Chrome()
    async with get_session(service, browser) as session:
        await session.get("https://www.flashscore.com")
        accept = await session.wait_for_element(2, "#onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
        await accept.click()
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        i = 0
        countries_clicker = await session.wait_for_element(5, ".lmc__block")
        for country in countries_clicker:
            count = len(countries_clicker)
            if country.is_displayed():
                await country.click()
                i +=1
                print(f"Количество итераций: {i}/{count}")

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(flashscore())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Синхронный код, который работает отлично:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def flashscore():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com")
    accept = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
    time.sleep(10)
    i = 0
    countries_clicker = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".lmc__block")
    for country in countries_clicker:
        count = len(countries_clicker)
        if country.is_displayed():
            country.click()
            i +=1
            print(f"Количество итераций: {i}/{count}")
    driver.close()

flashscore()
```

Comment: Насколько я вижу в документации arsenic, функции `wait_for_elements` не существует, есть только `wait_for_element`

Comment: @andreymal, не работает `wait_for_element`. Это я уже что только не пробовал, что уже даже `wait_for_elements` несуществующий впихнул

Comment: wait_for_element возвращает всего один элемент и по нему нельзя пройтись циклом. Вы можете после него воткнуть получение списка всех элементов `countries_clicker = await session.get_elements(".lmc__block")` — у меня такое заработало

Comment: @andreymal, заменил `countries_clicker = await session.wait_for_element(5, ".lmc__block")` на `countries_clicker = await session.get_elements(".lmc__block")` и все  заработало. Спасибо большое, долго не мог найти решение да и у меня в коде дальше много подобного и можно сказать вы мне упростили дальнейшую работу)!

Comment: Заменять немножко опасно, если вдруг элементы не успеют появиться на странице, то get_elements не будет их дожидаться и может вернуть пустой список

Comment: @andreymal, сейчас еще раз попробовал только без замены как вы сказали и работает все также, но зато не будет рисков что элементы не успеют появиться

Comment: @andreymal, а может будет практичнее перед `countries_clicker = await session.get_elements(".lmc__block")` делать задержку чтоб все успевало появиться с помощью `await asyncio.sleep` и не писать `countries_clicker = await session.wait_for_element(5, ".lmc__block")`?

Comment: Вы заранее не угадаете какая задержка нужна. Сегодня вы поставили 10 секунд и всё работает, а завтра интернет немножко потупит, на загрузку уйдёт 15-20 секунд и элементы не успеют появиться